# How to Reset A Map Polyline

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

In my application I am using the new map control for wp8. I have my route being tracked when the user chooses to do so, but when the user opts to turn the route tracking off, I am not sure how to clear the Polyline from the map?

I call my InitializeMapPolyline in the constructor

```
private void InitializeMapPolyLine()
    {
        _line = new MapPolyline();
        //_line.StrokeColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
        _line.StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 106, 0, 255);
        _line.StrokeThickness = 5;
        Map.MapElements.Add(_line);
    }
```

and as the position of the user changes I add the coordinate to the map

```
_line.Path.Add(myGeoCoordinate);
```

But then the user may opt to quit tracking of their route, in which case I need to remove this from the map control. How might I accomplish this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply removing it?

```
Map.MapElements.Remove(_line);
```

Comment: That does work. I'm wondering though, since I call `InitializeMapPolyLine()` which adds the line to the map `Map.MapElements.Add(_line);` in the page's constructor, and I am removing it in an appbar click event, which toggles the tracking ability, when the user wants to track themselves again, the line wont show correct? I'm thinking I should add `InitializeMapPolyLine()` in the same event that toggles the tracking, so when tracking is on a new MapPolyline is created and placed on the map. Am I thinking of this correctly? (Hopefully that made sense).

Comment: Yap, you can do that. But if you want it turned on by default, you still need to call it from the constructor.

Comment: ok, it isn't on by default. I am tracking the location with a PushPin, but if the user wants to see their route then that is an option for them as well.